# Trace Diagnostics on Windows Azure not working when Defining Compile constants in msbuild

Tags: azure, msbuild

I have a Cloud Service project on windows Azure that have been running just fine with diagnostics working. Today I needed to add a compile constant in the build.

```
#if INCLUDE_LICENSE_MANAGER

#endif
```

I did this by giving msbuild the arguments /p:DefineConstants=INCLUDE_LICENSE_MANAGER but this resulted in the Trace written to diagnostics stopped working. (using the azure trace listener to log to blob storage ect)

So what have I misunderstood about Compile Constants since it caused my tracing to stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually related to **MSBuild** and the **DefineConstants** parameter.

When you use `/p:DefineConstants=INCLUDE_LICENSE_MANAGER`, MSBuild overrides the conditional compilation symbols already defined in your .csproj file (as noted [here](http://www.tomatosoft.biz/blog/2011/11/11/msbuild-override-symbols-already-definded-in-csproj-file/), but it is very easy to reproduce in a simple Console Application).
The `TRACE` conditional compilation symbol which is defined by default (both for Debug and Release configuration when creating a new project) is not defined anymore, thus preventing most methods from the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to be executed.

In your case, you should manually define the *TRACE* constant in your MSBuild command, by using `/p:DefineConstants="INCLUDE_LICENSE_MANAGER;TRACE"`.